# GWT exception "Cannot Serialize" when using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, gwt, serialization

I'm getting "com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException:", when employing GWT+Hibernate. I tried to Google, but most of the error is in the context of List (I found a similiar thread here [GWT Cannot Serialize My Object from Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319980/gwt-cannot-serialize-my-object-from-hibernate/4327225#4327225)). I'm getting this when I'm trying to pass an object of type UserPreference through RPC. Below are the classes for your reference.

```
public class UserPreference implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private UserInfo userInfo;

// other attributes

public UserPreference() {
    super();
}
    // getters/setters
}
```

// UserInfo Class

```
public class UserInfo implements Serializable{

private int id;
private String name;
private String cuid;    
private UserRole role;
private DbSchema favDb;

public UserInfo() {
    super();
}
}
```

//DbSchema class

```
public class DbSchema implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int id;
private String name;
private int port;
private String host;
private String sidName;
private String userName;
private String password;
private String defaultConfigId;

public DbSchema() {
    super();
}

    //getters/setters
}
```

I don't know what the problem is with my 'DbSchema' class. All the data is being retrieved fine from the DB, and when I make DbSchema instance as 'transient' in UserInfo class, this is working fine. I didn't try with Dozer or Gilead, but just want to know the actual issue with the code.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem because Hibernate is [lazy fetching](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20533.html) referenced objects: when UserInfo object is created by Hibernate, `favDb` is not pointing to an actual `DbSchema` object but to a Hibernate-generated proxy (this is actually implemented via getter/setter not the field itself).

A general solution is to create a DTO (data transfer object). See this blogpost for explanation and a solution: http://hibernate4gwt.sourceforge.net/hibernate_gwt_lazy_issue.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter... that saved me a lot of time...I had read about this problem from some other posts, but I was unable to figure it out. Your explanation was simple and clear. In my case I had to fetch DbSchema details too along with UserInfo. So I just manipulated hibernate mapping file to do that ( fetch="join"). I got rid of Dozer and Gilead for the time being...